# Flutter Error:: Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, apk

I wanted to build apk flutter app for test in phone by Android Studio. I already have flutter app. I tried a build APK. I did this way:

I clicked Build > Flutter > Build APK in Android Studio.

results:

```
C:\SRC\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Can Ahmet\StudioProjects\myapp\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 73

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_72oyoy28ktxj66hn01bbfxy4$_run_closure5@613623d3] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 11s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           18,0s
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app / build.gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I controlled place of the buildTypes. But i guess it's right. Its in android{}.

How can i solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720145/could-not-find-method-buildtypes-for-arguments-on-project-app-of-type-org-g     you build types in wrong place

Comment: @АлександрИнженер look carefully buildType in android. So correct place.

Comment: you have  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug?

Comment: @АлександрИнженер Yes as a code. In the buildTypes.

Comment: try comment this line and run `flutter build apk` or in android studio `build->flutter->build apk` sometimes help `flutter clean` then`flutter pub update` and rebuild apk

Comment: That is worked! flutter clean after that flutter build apk. But now i have new problem.